# Error establishing a database connection after site migration?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, database-migration

I've moved a wordpress site to a different hosting service and getting the following error message when opening the site:

```
Error establishing a database connection
This either means that the username and password information in your wp-
config.php file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at 
localhost. This could mean your host’s database server is down.

Are you sure you have the correct username and password?
Are you sure that you have typed the correct hostname?
Are you sure that the database server is running?
```

I receive the same message when I attempt to access `sitedomain.com/wp-admin`

I imported the database and in cpanel I created a new user and added all privileges and added the user to the database. In cpanel I can access the database via phpMyAdmin without issue.

I can also connect to the database via MySQL Workbench using the newly created username & password using 'sitedomain.com' as the network address.

My config.php file:

```
<?php

define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

define('DB_NAME', 'databaseName');

define('DB_USER', 'userName');

/* MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');

/* MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');     

/* Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/* The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/* WordPress Database Table prefix. */

$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/* Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Where `databaseName` is the name of the newly created database, `userName` is the newly created user in cpanel with it's own `password`.

I've tried using the ip instead of `localhost` and also tried switching the `siteurl` to `http://www.sitedomain.com` and home to `http.sitedomain.com/dir` where `dir` is the wordpress directory.

I created a `testconnection.php` file in the main wordpress folder:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'userName', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Where `userName` and `password` are again the new user & password created in cpanel added to the database with all privileges.

Navigating to `sitedomain.com/dir/textconnection.php` displays the following:

```
Could not connect: Access denied for user 'userName'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Are their other configuration details I am forgetting to change? How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Are you sure that your new host runs the database on localhost? My host has a separate server for database instances and I have to enter the database domain (usually something like sql.domain.com).

Comment: @vtcajones I can connect via MySQL Workbench using the same username & password in my wp-config file which uses 'sitedomain.com' as the network address.

Comment: I wound up switching to a different server instance where another one of our wordpress sites is hosted, imported the database there, granting permissions to the same user that the other site uses and I had no issues.

Comment: Strange, yeah, my next suggestion was going to be contact your host ;) Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Is your database running at `localhost`?

Localhost might not be in your hosts file. Change localhost to `127.0.0.1` (assuming it is at your localhost) or else to the ip of the database machine.

Comment: I tried `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, as well as the server ip.